# Pass an iterable to a function and iterate twice in rust

Tags: rust

I have a function which looks like

```rust
fn do_stuff(values: HashSet<String>) {
  // Count stuff
  for s in values.iter() {
    prepare(s);
  }
  // Process stuff 
  for s in values.iter() {
    process(s);
  }
}
```

This works fine.  For a unit test, I want to pass a two value collection where the elements are passed in a known order.  (Processing them in the other order won't test the case I am trying to test.)  `HashSet` doesn't guarantee an order, so I would like to pass a `Vec` instead.

I would like to change the argument to `Iterable`, but it appears that only `IntoIter` exists.  I tried

```rust
fn do_stuff<C>(values: C)
where C: IntoIterator<Item=String>
 {
  // Count stuff
  for s in values {
    prepare(s);
  }
  // Process stuff 
  for s in values {
    process(s);
  }
}
```

which fails because the first iteration consumes `values`.  The compiler suggests borrowing `values`, but

```rust
fn do_stuff<C>(values: C)
where C: IntoIterator<Item=String>
 {
  // Count stuff
  for s in &values {
    prepare(s);
  }
  // Process stuff 
  for s in values {
    process(s);
  }
}
```

fails because

> the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&C`

I could probably make something with `clone` work, but the actual set will be large and I would like to avoid copying it if possible.

Thinking about that, the signature probably should be `do_stuff(values: &C)`, so if that makes the problem simpler, then that is an acceptable solution.

SO suggests [Writing a generic function that takes an iterable container as parameter in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940068/writing-a-generic-function-that-takes-an-iterable-container-as-parameter-in-rust) as a related question, but that is a lifetime problem.  I am not having problems with lifetimes.

It looks like [How to create an `Iterable` trait for references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822965/how-to-create-an-iterable-trait-for-references-in-rust) may actually be the solution.  But I'm having trouble getting it to compile.

My first attempt is

```rust
pub trait Iterable {
    type Item;
    type Iter: Iterator<Item = Self::Item>;
    fn iterator(&self) -> Self::Iter;
}

impl Iterable for HashSet<String> {
    type Item = String;
    type Iter = HashSet<String>::Iterator;
    fn iterator(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

which fails with

```
error[E0223]: ambiguous associated type
   --> src/file.rs:178:17
    |
178 |     type Iter = HashSet<String>::Iterator;
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: use fully-qualified syntax: `<HashSet<std::string::String> as Trait>::Iterator`
```

Following that suggestion:

```rust
impl Iterable for HashSet<String> {
    type Item = String;
    type Iter = <HashSet<std::string::String> as Trait>::Iterator;
    fn iterator(&self) -> Self::Iter {
        self.iter()
    }
}
```

failed with

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Trait`
   --> src/file.rs:178:50
    |
178 |     type Iter = <HashSet<std::string::String> as Trait>::Iterator;
    |                                                  ^^^^^ use of undeclared type `Trait`
```

The rust documents don't seem to include `Trait` as a known type.  If I replace `Trait` with `HashSet`, it doesn't recognize `Iterator` or `IntoIter` as the final value in the expression.

## Implementation of accepted answer

Attempting to implement @eggyal answer, I was able to get this to compile

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn do_stuff<I>(iterable: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator + Copy,
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    // Count stuff
    for s in iterable {
        prepare(s.as_ref());
    }
    // Process stuff
    for s in iterable {
        process(s.as_ref());
    }
}

fn prepare(s: &str) {
    println!("prepare: {}", s)
}
fn process(s: &str) {
    println!("process: {}", s)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test_cluster {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn doit() {
        let vec: Vec<String> = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string(), "c".to_string()];
        let set = vec.iter().cloned().collect::<HashSet<_>>();
        do_stuff(&vec);
        do_stuff(&set);
    }
}
```

which had this output

```
 ---- simple::test_cluster::doit stdout ----
prepare: a
prepare: b
prepare: c
process: a
process: b
process: c
prepare: c
prepare: b
prepare: a
process: c
process: b
process: a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`IntoIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html) is not only implemented by the collection types themselves, but in most cases (including [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-17) and [`HashSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#impl-IntoIterator-22)) ***it is also implemented by their borrows*** (yielding an iterator of borrowed items).  Moreover, immutable borrows are always [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/marker/trait.Copy.html).  So you can do:

```rust
fn do_stuff<I>(iterable: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator + Copy,
    I::Item: AsRef<str>,
{
    // Count stuff
    for s in iterable {
        prepare(s);
    }
    // Process stuff 
    for s in iterable {
        process(s);
    }
}
```

And this would then be invoked by passing in a *borrow* of the relevant collection:

```rust
let vec = vec!["a", "b", "c"];
let set = vec.iter().cloned().collect::<HashSet<_>>();
do_stuff(&vec);
do_stuff(&set);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5df2e539fad1501403e3ca921b78d239).

However, depending on your requirements (whether all items must first be prepared before any can be processed), it may be possible in this case to combine the preparation and processing into a single pass of the iterator.

Comment: That appears to work if you use `s.as_ref()` instead of `s`.  Is `s` itself directly usable, without the `as_ref()`?  If I tried using it, I got errors about an associated type and suggestions to constrain `<I as IntoIterator>::Item`

Comment: @TroyDaniels: The [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69166324/3) of this answer explicitly required an `&&str` item type, which wouldn't require `.as_ref()`; however that would also limit you to iterators with that item type, whereas this is more general. Up to you which you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators over containers can be cloned if you want to iterate the container twice, so accepting an `IntoIterator + Clone` should work for you. Example code:

```
fn do_stuff<I>(values: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator + Clone,
{
    // Count stuff
    for s in values.clone() {
        prepare(s);
    }
    // Process stuff
    for s in values {
        process(s);
    }
}
```

You can now pass in e.g. either a hash set or a vector, and both of them can be iterated twice:

```
let vec = vec!["a", "b", "c"];
let set: HashSet<_> = vec.iter().cloned().collect();
do_stuff(vec);
do_stuff(set);
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3221f7dc7e608d508618927eeac49e30))

Comment: OP does not want to clone the container

Comment: Can an iterator of a `HashSet` or `Vec` be safely cloned?

Comment: This doesn't necessitate cloning the containers. I chose to pass in the containers themselves, so they are cloned, but you can also pass in iterators over the containers, like `vec.iter()` or `set.iter()`.